# Continuation of proof of intersection of two unions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble continuing a proof of the intersection of two unions. What I'm basically trying to reach is 
$$(X \cup Y) \cap (X \cup Z) = X \cup (Y \cap Z)$$
Here is what I've been able to do so far:
$$(x \in X \lor x \in Y) \land (x \in X \lor x \in Z)$$
$$\Bigl((x \in X \lor x \in Y) \land x \in X\Bigr) \lor \Bigl((x \in X \lor x \in Y) \land x \in Z\Bigr)$$
$$\Bigl((x \in X \land x \in X) \lor (x \in Y \land x \in X)\Bigr) \lor \Bigl((x \in X \land x \in Z) \lor (x \in Y \land x \in Z)\Bigr)$$
$$\Bigl((x \in X) \lor (x \in Y \land x \in X)\Bigr) \lor \Bigl((x \in X \land x \in Z) \lor (x \in Y \land x \in Z)\Bigr)$$

And I think if I were to change something in the latter part (after the union symbol in the middle), I would rather easily arrive at what I'm trying to reach, but I can't figure out what it is that I need to change. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems to be on the right track! Try applying the "absorption law" to the left side: $x \in X \vee (x \in Y \wedge x \in X)$ is logically equivalent to $x \in X$.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about doing that, but then it occured to me that that would cause loss of information, but that doesn't really matter in this context, or am I mistaken?

Comment: No, the absorption law does not result in a loss of information. Once we know that $x \in X \vee (x \in Y \wedge x \in X)$ is true, then either $x \in X$ or $x \in Y \wedge x \in X$. In either case, $x \in X$. But could we say anything about the truth value of $x \in Y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line you used the following law

$p \wedge (q \vee r) \iff (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r)$.

If you're allowed to use such a laws, the question is just a translation from sets to propositions and can be solved easily using the following law

$p \vee (q \wedge r) \iff (p \vee q) \wedge (p \vee r)$.

We have

$(x \in X \vee x \in Y) \wedge (x \in X \vee x \in Z)$

(using the mentioned law in the right to left direction)

$\iff x \in X \vee (x \in Y \wedge x \in Z)$

*Voilà!*